# Can't we use other jdk other than IBM JDK in RAD WebSphere?

Tags: java, sdk, websphere, rad

I am using RAD WebSphere in my project. We can define which JDK to use by defining the argument -vm in eclipse.ini. But I found that we can only use the IBM JDK(or something as IBM SDK) in Websphere. Is that true?

I am looking forward to your opinions.

Answer (score 4):

WebSphere traditional can only be used with the java image that comes packaged with the product, which is essentially the IBM JDK.

However, for WebSphere Liberty you can use whatever java you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!